# Durandal.js - composition vs widget

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

i want create one div ( basically it will containt listbox) , and i want to use the div in different pages,

which is the best option to use in duarandal.js?

```
Composition
```

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/

> Widget

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Widget/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, think of using the `compose` binding as *templates*, and widgets as *user controls*

There's not quite enough information in your question for me to offer a suggestion on which is the right choice for you, but I'll provide some comparison for the two below, which should make it easier for you to choose.

---

**Durandal's compose binding** can be used to render, or inject, one view as part of another.  For example, a menu.html may be defined that can be used to display menu items.  This is similar to the concept of a jQuery template, or a "partial view" in ASP.Net MVC.  A composed view can either use the parent's view model as its data source, or it can have its own view model.

The compose binding is most useful when you have a view and/or view model that can be used **as is** in multiple places.

**Durandal's widgets**, on the other hand, use composition internally, but are designed to abstract the "parts" of the widget so that one widget can be configured differently on each view where it is rendered.  A widget can have `parts`, and these parts can be exposed through the widget interface.

Durandal widgets are most useful when you want to create some functionality that can be used across multiple views, but the implementations may differ.

Comment: Is it possible to add a `<div> <div data-bind="compose: 'partials/justIncludeMyHeader.html'"></div> </div>` to the file containing `#applicationHost` -- as a sibling to this div? Meaning, outside of `shell.html` but inside `indexOrLayout.html` as a sibling to `<div id="applicationHost"></div>`...?

Comment: You could probably get this work if you manually apply the ko bindings.  Try asking this as a separate question, and you'll get a lot better response.

Comment: thx for the input I think I will create a question -- cheers.